# DELETE With Output clause issue in sql server

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

We have archival process which deletes old records from transaction table and maintain records in archival tables.

The transaction table has more than 200k records. We are archiving records based on status and recorded date. This archival process has been done by SQL Job which is been scheduled every day.

Here we have written the statement:

```
DELETE TOP (5000)
OUTPUT col1, col2, col3 INTO archival table
FROM Maintable
WHERE condition
```

At times, the records were deleted from main table but not inserted to archival table. We checked whether any other db activities been happen. None of the activities been happen.

We are seeing this issue rarely (like monthly 2 to 3 times). There is no error mentioned in SQL job  history.

No issue in statement level too. Is there any possibility to get this issue?

Comment: TOP without an ORDER BY is basically a collection of random matching rows btw.

Comment: [From the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/output-clause-transact-sql) `The whole operation is atomic. Either both the INSERT statement and the nested DML statement that contains the OUTPUT clause execute, or the whole statement fails.`. So no, there is no way that the delete could complete and not the insert (unless you have found a bug). The likely answer is that someone, or something is deleting records without the `OUTPUT`, and you just haven't managed to trace the culprit yet.

Comment: Anyway whatever records deleted should be in output table and that should be inserted into the archival table..Isn't it? Are you suspecting this is only the issue...

Comment: Yes, there are two options (as far as I can tell), **1.** You have found a bug in a fairly basic operation in SQL Server **2.** However you are checking for *"other db activities"* is missing something. How are you monitoring that nothing is deleting records without inserting them to the archive? If this should happen for every delete, then why not just set up a trigger?